# opencv - prediction collision of ball

Tags: c++, opencv, collision-detection

I want to do a project, which will consist in detecting possible collision of the pool balls, using opencv, webcam and C++ programming language. For now I just want to  prediction collision of 2 balls on minibilard table. I detect them by change rgb to hsv and then use thereshold, in future i will probably use another method for detect a random amount of balls, but it's not so important now.

So, for now I can detect two balls, i know their position, radius, now I'm thinking how to  predict whether there will be a collision between them, if we if we assume that they will move in straight lines. I think that I should check their position in every frame update (and i have to know a time between frames in my webcamera) and by that, i I will be able to determine the value of speed, acceleration and direction of the ball. So, if i will know those parameters for for both balls, I will be able to determine where can they collide, and then, using parametric equastion I will be able to check, if they will be on collision point on the same time.

I wonder if this is the right approach to the problem, maybe there is a simpler and more effective method to do this?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Karol

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track for your project, but on the wrong track for a good SO question. This question is too broad. Please see [help/on-topic] and [tour].

Comment: if you assume the movement is linear, then yes, what you suggest should work. however you should know that you can find other factors harder to predict, like deceleration of the ball. But you can always create at least 2 lines  (one for each side of the ball), and see if it intersects a circle (the other ball). This will tell you at least if the trayectory will lead to a collision, then you need to predict is where it will stop, if it is before or after the other ball... I think that part is the hard one, unless you have enough frames to calculate the deceleration.

Answer (score 0):

#### This sounds like you are on track for a good project...

Calculating acceleration seems, from what I briefly read [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252431/how-to-calculate-acceleration-from-discrete-samples-of-velocity), reasonably difficult though. So as a preliminary step, you could just assume a constant velocity. So take the difference between a balls position last frame and current frame as a vector and add it on to the current frames position to find where it will be next frame. Doing this for both balls will allow you to check for a collision.

You can check for a collision by comparing the distance between the balls centers using Pythagoras to the sum of their radii. If the sum of their radii will be greater than the distances between their centers, you have a collision.

Obviously, calculating one frame ahead is not very useful, but if you assume a constant velocity or manage to calculate their acceleration, there is no reason to why you can't calculate 30 or 100 frames in the future with this method.

I recently made a billiards ball simulation in javascript which you could take a quick look at [here](http://joeiddon.me/UltiBouncingBall/BallHtml.html) if you want to see how this could work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

For now I just wanna test my calculations so I've just made a simple animation, rectangle moves with constans speed, and i just  wanted to check the speed in every frame, I'm quite confused becouse speed value are between 0.136859 pixel/msec to 0.0113137 pixel/msec. It's a simple animation with one yellow rectangle and black background so it's not becouse of noise or something like this, so i really don't know, why i get those results.